# Why is this code in g ++ / clang wrong, there is no error in VS2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, gcc

```
#include <iostream>

class Name {
public:
    Name(int i) : a(i) {}
    int a;
};
void func(Name& a) {
    a.a = 2;
    std::cout << a.a << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    func(Name(1));//error
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this code in g ++ / clang wrong, there is no error in VS2013?

Comment: The code is wrong in Visual C++ 2013, too. It may produce a binary from the code, but not without printing a warning first, and if there is no warning, then you are using the compiler with the wrong options.

Comment: There is a warning, but it might be [turned off by default](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2010/12/14/off-by-default-compiler-warnings-in-visual-c/).